# Why is image from sprite limited to screen height?

Tags: html, css, ipad

I have combined several large images into a Sprite. Each image when displayed full size, is larger than my iPad screen size. If there is a single image in the sprite, the full image is available to view. I simply scroll to the right or down to see the parts of the image which don’t fit on the screen initially.

If there are several images in the sprite, I can scroll right to see the part of the image which doesn’t fit on the screen initially, however the height of the image is truncated to fit the screen height, so I can’t scroll down to see the rest of it. If I turn my iPad from landscape to portrait the displayable image enlarges to the portrait height of the screen.
How can I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="general.css">

<style>
#img1 {
background: url("bates-sprite.jpeg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
object-fit: none;
width:  2049px;
height: 1537px;
}

#img1 {object-position: 0 0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img id="img1" src="bates-sprite.jpeg" alt="Camberley Mail front page report">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know why the monthly image sprite behaved differently from the single image sprite, but simply putting the image inside a div solved the problem.

```
<div>
<img id="img1" src="bates-sprite.jpeg" alt="Camberley Mail front page report">
</div>
```